# подскажите как передать название из кнопки из html в функцию django ведь у кнопки название динамическое (dima1) (dima2) (dima n)

Tags: python, django

Вот 4 кнопки для принятия человека в друзья. Как мне обработать нажатие каждой кнопки?

Каждая кнопка находится в форме, привязанной к каждому из списка юзеров.

[image: рисунок]

```
<h3>подписчики</h3>
            {% for follower in aaa %}
                <h3>{{ follower.from_user }}</h3>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button>принять от {{ follower.from_user }}</button>
                </form>
            {% endfor %}
```

```
def friends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот через такой костыль теперь могу получить имя пользователя, которого принял в друзья:

```
<h3>подписчики</h3>
            {% for follower in aaa %}
                <h3>{{ follower.from_user }}</h3>
                    <a href="{% url 'userprofils' usernames=follower.from_user %}">принять</a>
            {% endfor %}
```

```
path('friends/<str:usernames>/', views.friendss, name='userprofils'),
```

```
def friendss(request, usernames):
    print(usernames)
    return redirect('/home/friends/')
```